# "MongoError: pool destroyed" in NodeRED

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-red, azure-iot-edge

We are having windows server on which linux VM is installed.

On windows server we have -
MongoDB 3.6.17 Community Edition /
Node.js v10.19.0

On Linux VM we have installed NodeRed container /
Node.js v16.17.1

As mongoDB and Nodered are in same subnet we are able to establish communication between them.

On linux VM we have installed Azure IoT Edge and Nodered container is running on the top of it.

I am fetching data from MongoDB into NodeRED and then processing it further.
This flow works absolutely fine, however in some cases I am getting this error - "MongoError: pool destroyed".
After this I am not able to fetch data from MongoDB.
Once I Open/Close debug node and deploy the flow it starts to work again.

I'm using:

- node-red-node-mongodb (0.2.5)

Can anyone please suggest what might be the root cause for this problem?
Can the differences in Node.js versions in windows and linux create an issue?

Please refer image for your reference -

[image]

Comment: NodeJS v10.x has been out of support since 24 Apr 2018 (https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule)

Comment: As an aside, any version of Node-RED that will run on NodeJS v10 is also very out of support, you should look to upgrade. Please edit the question with details of which MongoDB node you are using and anything shown in the Node-RED log at the time of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using "node-red-node-mongodb(0.2.5)"  to fetch data from mongoDB.  We have a linux VM on which Azure IoT Edge is installed and Nodered container is running on the top of it. I am assuming the error occurs when the PC is restarted.

Comment: I have updated the question with details, can you please have a look